# Unable to Connect to Local Service Fabric Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Recently i uninstalled Service Fabric SDK 1.4 and installed Service Fabric SDK 2.0, post that i am unable to create / connect to the local Service fabric cluster. I am getting the below mentioned exception. I tried restarting the VM to ensure that the environment variables are reflected. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling the sdk couple of times but did not see it getting resolved. Please let me know if anyone faced this issue and if resolved what actions do i need to take care.

> Waiting for Naming Service to be ready. This may take a few minutes...
>   Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 
>   'IFabricApplicationManagementClient6'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for 
>   the interface with IID '{B01E63EE-1EA4-4181-95C7-983B32E16848}' failed due to the following error: No such interface 
>   supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
>   At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1:521 char:12
>   +     [void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @connParams)
>   +            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], InvalidCastException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster

I tried to follow the steps mentioned in this link to setup up my local cluster
[Link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-get-started-with-a-local-cluster/)

Below are the components installed

[image]

Comment: Can you open up Add/Remove Programs, search for "fabric", and share the versions of Service Fabric and the Service Fabric SDK. This sounds like an interface mismatch.

Comment: @Sean McKenna , Sure, i have edited my question displaying the fabric installations. please let me know if something is mismatching.

Comment: @Sean McKenna, Is there anything else that i need to suspect, like i have installed both VS2015 & 2013. Any clue about which component it is trying to get from the Com Object or any clue that you could suggest

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue working with Service Fabric Actors and I hit the same error message when my Actor Client was trying to connect to the Actor Service. After hours and hours of trying different things I realized that my Service Fabric implementation and the Actor client are using **different versions of Service Fabric NuGet Packages**.

After I used the same version in my Actor Client (I basically downgraded it) then the client started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the old Service Fabric bits did not uninstall properly and is getting picked up by new binaries, which could not find the desired interface.

Can you try to uninstall the current bits, reboot the machine and then install again? That should work.

Comment: Yes, i had tried to identify all the components related to service fabric and deleted all the related folders, cleared temp folders, program file folders, etc. Then rebooted and then installed the new service fabric and then again rebooted the  machine and tried.

Comment: You are hitting this because new binaries are definitely picking up old native binaries from somewhere in system path. After you uninstall can you check if you still have any fabric binaries on system path?